# Create a new JPA Entity to produce a new object from two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hello programming council, this is my first use of JPA in anger.

I have 2 Tables:

```
    Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;
    
    @Column(name="budget")
    private double budget;
    
    @Column(name="savings")
    private String savings;
    
    @Column(name="archive")
    private String archive;


    Entity
@Table(name="Transaction")
public class Transaction {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="transaction_no")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long transactionNo;
    
    @Column(name="transaction_date")
    private String transactionDate;
    
    @Column(name="transaction_category")
    private String transactionCategory;
    
    @Column(name="transaction_description")
    private String transactionDescription;
    
    @Column(name="transaction_amount")
    private double transcationAmount;
    
    @Column(name="transaction_auto")
    private String transactionAuto;
```

I want to create a new object called Tile which will contain String category and String balance, the SQL for which would be:

```
select t.transaction_category as category, sum(t.transaction_amount) as balance
from budgeteer.category c 
join budgeteer.transaction t
on c.category = t.transaction_category
group by t.transaction_category;
```

What is the easiest/best way for me to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen constructor queries? JPQL "select new package.Tile(t.transactionCategory, sum(t.transcationAmount)) from Transaction t group by t.transactionCategory" You aren't using the join, but can add it to that if needed using JPA 2.1

Comment: I haven't, I'll go research them, though an initial search doesn't quite show me what I want.

Comment: Show me what you want as it isn't clear what you are looking for in a Tile object - you might want to create a database view and then an entity overtop of it if you want to use it in queries as an entity. There are far too many options to guess what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a little more research, I discovered that I could actually just do this with the same Entity, repository and service without generating a table. You just need to leave out the @Table annotation when you create your entity.